# phpPDO insert дважды добавляет

Tags: php, pdo

Привет всем! 
Делаю запрос инсерт, но выполняется оно дважды. Это что баг?

```
<?php 
//database credentials
define('DB_HOSTNAME', '127.0.0.1');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'user');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'db');
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'fc_');


$dsn = "mysql:host=" . DB_HOSTNAME . ";dbname=" . DB_DATABASE . ";charset=" . DB_CHARSET;
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "categories SET name = 110 ");

        $stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел ответ: проблема была в htaccess. Там правила rewrite. Из-за этого файл обрабатывался дважды.